# How can I turn the behavior of `gedit something & disown` into the default behavior when calling gedit from the command line?

Tags: shell, terminal, alias, job-control, disown

When I `gedit` files from the command line, it's always locking the terminal, and I'm tired of explicitly commanding a detached process for it.

I tried to alias `gedit` as something like `gedit $* & disown`, but either that's not the right syntax or you're not allowed to overload executable binary commands with aliases (tried using that in a .bash_aliases function,

```
alias gedit=editorz

function editorz()
{
  gedit $* & disown
}
```

), but it doesn't take.

So how do I make the command `gedit test.txt` not lock the originating terminal window?

Comment: Depending on your shell, "function" may not be supported. The POSIX-compatible way to define a function is without it. `func_name() {...; }`

Comment: Already using some functions that way (for non-trivial aliases).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should work: are you sure your `.bash_aliases` is read? (It's not a standard file, but it might be sourced by your `~/.bashrc`. If you're confused about `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, see [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile).)

There's a bug in your function: it should be

```
editorz () {
  gedit "$@" & disown
}
```

Your version doesn't work on file names containing spaces or shell wildcards. The `function` keyword is optional.

You can call the function `gedit` (and dispense with the alias altogether), but then you need to tell the shell that the call inside the function is to the command and not to the function:

```
gedit () {
  command gedit "$@" & disown
}
```

Note that if you've accidentally started gedit in the foreground (i.e. locking your terminal), you can put it in the background by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal, and entering the command `bg`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that the `function editorz()` is defined before the alias.

I've tried your approach and it worked without a problem.

Comment: Hmm, will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Opening `gedit` from the Utilities folder (instead of a terminal) solves the problem for me

Answer (score -2):

just add the following alias:

```
alias gedit='gedit -b'
```

the `-b` option means run in the background

Comment: `Unknown option -b`, and I'm on a very GNOMish system, meaning it shouldn't lack too many features of a GNOME app like `gedit`...

Comment: Same here, -b option doesn't exist for me.